# Problemas com evento onKey

Tags: android

Estou dando manutenção em um aplicativo android feita com Eclipse(ADT).

Tem uma caixa de texto, onde será digitado o código de barras do produto, bem como essa leitura pode ser feita com o leitor. Quando abre a Activity, se digitado um valor na caixa de texto, o evento `onKey` é disparado duas vezes(up e down). Se for digitado "enter" é realizado uma pesquisa; o método de pesquisa dá foco na próxima caixa e apaga o CB quando concluído. Isso funciona a primeira vez, tanto digitando quanto utilizando o leitor(o leitor dá um enter no final).

O problema é: se eu tentar ler ou digitar outro código de barras, os eventos não são disparados. Não é gerado log. Só vai ser disparado se eu pressionar a tecla backspace.

```
txtProduto.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

   @Override
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      Log.i("keycode", Integer.toString(keyCode));
      if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
       executarPesquisa();
       return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

 });
```

Tem uns outros eventos que não sei para que serve, não sei se está afetando. Já comentei eles e não resolve.

```
txtProduto.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    strFocus = "P";
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtProduto.getWindowToken(), 0); 

   }
});
```

Esse executar pesquisa chama o método `execute`de uma classe que implmenta `AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>`

Comment: Tirar o evento keylistener e tratar no evento focuschange esta fora de questão?

Comment: Vai dar não. Assim que for feita a leitura do código de barras precisa disparar a pesquisa. Preciso que identifique o enter pra realizar a pesquisa. O leitor "dá" o enter. Do jeito que tá só funciona uma vez.

Comment: Se o leitor dá o enter, o evento setOnFocusChangeListener ocorre. Nesse evento você pode chamar a pesquisa. Não seria viável?

Comment: vou dar uma olhada e te falo

Answer (score 1):

Tira o evento `setOnKeyListener` e implementa o evento `setOnFocusChangeListener`
dessa maneira:

```
  txtProduto.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!hasFocus ) {
           if ( !txtProduto.getText().toString().equals("")) {
              strFocus = "P";
              InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtProduto.getWindowToken(), 0); 

              executarPesquisa();
         }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Agora após o leitor inserir os números, está quebrando uma linha no edit.  Eu coloquei android:maxLines="1" mas ainda sim quebra uma linha e não perde o foco

Comment: Veja a configuração do leitor. Ele deve estar inserindo outra coisa diferente de <enter>

Comment: Resolvi colocando android:singleLine="true" , voltei o evento onKey, porém fiz um ´if´ para ver se o evento era up. Está funcionando assim por hora. Obrigado pela ajuda.